# 0x3 error using pdbstr (Source indexing)

Tags: c#, indexing

I am trying to use the PDBSTR.EXE tool to merge version information into a PDB file and from time to time I encounter the following error:
[result: error 0x3 opening K:\dev\main\bin\mypdbfile.pdb] <- can be a different PDB file.

An example of the command line that I use is:

```
pdbstr.exe -w -s:srcsrv -p:K:\dev\main\bin\mypdbfile.pdb -i:C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp517B.stream
```

Could you tell me what would cause error code 0x3?

If the error code is similar to the standard System error code 3 ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND, then it seems to think that the path K:\dev\main\bin\mypdbfile.pdb does NOT exist when in fact it DOES.
However please note that my K: drive is a SUBST'ed drive.

(System error code reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)

Do you know what the 0x3 error code could possibly mean?

Comment: If your K: drive refers to a network location, it could become unavailable due to network issues.

Comment: @jstreet The K: drive is a subst drive. We've tried using the non-subst drive as well and still the issue remains.

Comment: Is K: drive located on a network machine or not?

Comment: @jstreet No it's not.

Answer (score -1):

If this error code appears from time to time, then i guess the `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` might be the real problem.

I guess the cause is, i couldn't see any double quotes wrapping the path you've given as input. When the path contains a folder name with spaces in it, it breaks your path. For ex

```
pdbstr.exe -w -s:srcsrv -p:K:\dev\main\my folder with spaces\mypdbfile.pdb -i:C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp517B.stream
```

Add a double quote around the path and that might solve it. Hope it helps.

Comment: 1. We assumed that was the problem at first, but we've verified that the path does in fact exist. 
2. There are no files/folders with spaces
3. If spaces were the problem, it wouldn't be random. The fact that it's random means that it works most times, but some random times, it decides to fail on one pdb. Usually a larger pdb file.

Comment: The file might exists. System  will not be able to get the path you give as input when it contains spaces in it. It will just take the `path` until it encounters the space and tries to find a file there. In the example i gave, until `K:\dev\main\my` and ignores the rest. EDIT : okay, then it might be something else